# Error in checking if the strings are empty or not

Tags: java, android, string, if-statement

Can you guys tell me what really is the problem in this if statement,'getItem' and 'getQty 'are both strings

```
if((getQty != null && getQty.length()>0) || (getItem!= null && getItem.length()>0))
    {
     //do something
     }
  else
    {
      //do something
     }
```

Comment: what's the error? plz provide more info

Comment: Are those methods? If they are you are missing (). getQty(). getItem().

Comment: Probably in the "do something" part that you haven't shown.

Comment: This question is unanswerable until you tell us the symptoms of "the problem".

Comment: @KickButtowski iam really using this if inside the android app to check if the edittext fields are empty or not , when iam using the above code the app stops responding.

Comment: @RanjithVarma:- What is getQty and getItem? Are they methods?

Comment: consider using `!string.isEmpty()` instead of `string.length>0`

Comment: @RanjithVarma But you are not getting any errors? If the app just freezes, the problem might be inside the if statement.

Comment: `string.equals("")` is also helpful

Comment: @Eran Actually i have to add the edittext value into the table in the if a statement and in the else i have to make an alert or toast to show that the field is empty while clicking the add button

Comment: @RanjithVarma - What does the logcat say? Post the stack trace.

Comment: Are you checking for both qty and item to be non-empty together??

Comment: You probably need to change the || in the middle to &&

Comment: @RanjithVarma you should add android tag into your question. you should add these info that you are telling us into your question too

Comment: @TheLostMind My minimum sdk version is 8 so i think i cant use !string.isEmpty() as it actually support 9 and above

Comment: @TheLostMind sorry iam new to android when i used it ,the sdk error was displayed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ques title says `Error in checking if the strings are empty or not`

So assuming you meant both the strings to be non-empty together

```
if((getQty != null && getQty.length()>0) && (getItem!= null && getItem.length()>0))
```

Use `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking if the String is empty or not but in your code, it will let you know if string is empty or not but which string is empty and which one is not empty it will not clear, so you can use two if else statement instead of using gates,
 **Here is the modification of your code**

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class EmptyString{

    public static void main(String []args){
         String getQty = "abc";
         String getItem = "";
       if(getQty != null && getQty.length()>0)
        {
         System.out.println("String " + getQty + " is not empty");
         }
       else
        {
         System.out.println("String " + getQty + " is empty");
        }
       if(getItem!= null && getItem.length()>0)
       {  
       System.out.println("String " + getItem + " is not empty");
        }
       else
       {
       System.out.println("String " + getItem + " is empty");
       }
    }
  }
```